# Refer to range in another file

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro in an open Excel file and want to refer to a cell in another open Excel file.

```
Range("b5").Activate
ActiveCell.Value = '[jobpl1.xlsx]Sheet1'!E16
```

It fails to compile.

Answer (score 1):

you should use :

```
Workbooks("Book1").Range("A1").Value = Workbooks("Book2").Range("A1").Value
```

or if you like your approach, then (if it's open)

```
ActiveCell.Value = "=('[Workbook1.xls]Sheet1'!$A$1)"
```

and in case it is closed, then use full path refference :

```
ActiveCell.Value = "=('C:\Users\username\Desktop\[Workbook1.xls]Sheet1'!$A$1)"
```

Answer (score 0):

To reference a range in another workbook, include the Workbook object and then the Range object:

```
Workbooks("Bla.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
```

OR

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()
    Dim FilePath As String
    '// File Path
    FilePath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents\"

    With Range("B1:B2")
        .Formula = "='" & FilePath & "[Bla.xlsx]Sheet1'!A1:A2"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

.activate is for workbooks and worksheets.

```
Range("b5").Select
ActiveCell.Value = '[jobpl1.xlsx]Sheet1'!E16
```

should work, but you should only select cells if you want to take the user to that place, never to do anything with that cell. (Because selecting cells wastes processing time.)
Instead asign the value directly to the cell in question:

```
Range("b5").value = "=('[Workbook1.xls]Sheet1'!$A$1)"
```

or use a range-variable instead.

```
dim temprange as range

set temprange = Range("B5")
tamprange.value =  "=('[Workbook1.xls]Sheet1'!$A$1)"
```

also if you want to asign a formula to a cell I suggest using .formula instead of .value which in this case likely won't matter, but when you read the contents of a cell it will matter and it will also matter if you write to the cell and the code is used on an Excel-Sheet with another country-setting. (.formula automatically recognizes language settings and converts , and . and the like.)