# Excel VBA IF Then Else Loop Output Not Returning Different Statements Based on Criteria

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement

Please help! I'm fairly new to working with macros and I am having trouble figuring out what I am doing wrong. I need a loop within a vba that will run down each row and check if Hours are either:

1. Greater than AvailHours Then the output for Reason would be "Not enough hours earned"
2. Hours < 4 Then the output for Reason would be "Pay for 4 hours"
3. Hours >= 4 Then the output for Reason would be "Pay for 8 hours"
4. If the output for Reason is "Not enough hours earned" then I need that row to move to the bottom

I have tried different macros and I either just get only one of the output statements all the way down the Reason column or errors in my macro not allowing it to complete.

Output I Get
[image: Output I Get]

```
'Check if enough Avail Sick Time Hours and Round Hours Worked
Range("EXCEPTIONS[Hours]").Select

For Each cell In Range("EXCEPTIONS[Hours]")

    If Value < "EXCEPTIONS[AvailHours]" Then
        Range("EXCEPTIONS[Reason]").Value = "Not enough hours earned"
    
    ElseIf Value < 4 Then
            Range("EXCEPTIONS[Reason]").Value = "Pay for 4 hours"
    
    ElseIf Value >= 4 Then
            Range("EXCEPTIONS[Reason]").Value = "Pay for 8 hours"

    
        
    End If

Next cell
```

Output I Need
[image: Output I Need]

Comment: Do you have a named range called `"EXCEPTIONS[Hours]"`? Or are you expecting that to be some sort of variable? Where is `value` coming from?

Comment: `If cell.Value`...   If you use `Option Explicit` it will point out undeclared variables.

Comment: braX - I have several spreadsheets in my workbook and the one I am working in is 'EXCEPTIONS'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33517477/refer-to-range-in-another-file

Comment: A spreadsheet or a workbook is the same thing. If your data is in the **worksheet** `EXCEPTIONS`, that's nice but has nothing to do with the expression `Range("EXCEPTIONS[Hours]")` which probably refers to the data range of column `Hours` in table `EXCEPTIONS`. Please share the rest of your code and a screenshot of the initial data so someone can actually help you with a working code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are dealing with an EXCEL table called 'EXCEPTIONS'. Try this, but explaining all that is wrong with your code will take a long time, so before asking for an explanation, please review the changes, and research them:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub DoIt()
    Dim ThisCell As Range

    For Each ThisCell In Range("EXCEPTIONS[Hours]")
        With Range("EXCEPTIONS[Reason]").Cells(ThisCell.Row - 1)
            If ThisCell < Range("EXCEPTIONS[AvailHours]").Cells(ThisCell.Row - 1) Then
                .Value = "Not enough hours earned"
            ElseIf ThisCell < 4 Then
                 .Value = "Pay for 4 hours"
            ElseIf ThisCell >= 4 Then
                 .Value = "Pay for 8 hours"
            End If
        End With
    Next ThisCell
    
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me!  Thank you for your help and the easy to understand code, tinazmu!  I see my error in not assigning cell as a range and not utilizing it within my code.

Answer (score 1):

try, modify accordingly

```
Sub CheckHoursEarned()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long, arr
    
    With Worksheets("EXCEPTIONS")
    
        lastRow = .Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        arr = .Range("D2:J" & lastRow).Value
    
        For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
            If arr(i, 1) < arr(i, 7) Then
                arr(i, 4) = "Not enough hours earned"
            ElseIf arr(i, 1) < 4 Then
                arr(i, 4) = "Pay for 4 hours"
            ElseIf arr(i, 1) >= 4 Then
                arr(i, 4) = "Pay for 8 hours"
            End If
        Next i
    
        .Range("D2:J" & lastRow).Value = arr
    
        Dim j As Long
        For j = lastRow To 2 Step -1
            If .Range("G" & j).Value = "Not enough hours earned" Then
                .Range("A" & j).EntireRow.Cut
                .Range("A" & lastRow + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
                lastRow = lastRow - 1
            End If
        Next j
        
        End With
    
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```